# Jasmine: Testing a function returning a promise

Tags: angularjs, testing, typescript, jasmine

I am writing tests using Jasmine for my angular application. All the tests are passing. My class looks like follows:

```
class xyz implements ng.IComponentController {
  private myList: ng.IPromise<MyList[]> ;
  //declare necessary variables
  /* @ngInject */
  constructor(private ListService: ListService,
              ) {
    this.myList = this.ListService.getList();
  }

  public onChange(): void {
    this.isNameUnique(this.name).then(function(unique){
      scope.isUnique = unique;
      scope.errorNameInput = !reg.test(scope.name) || !scope.isUnique;
      scope.myFunction({
        //do something
      });
    });
  }

  public isNameUnique(name: string): ng.IPromise<boolean> {
    return this.myList
    .then(
      (names) => {
        _.mapValues(names, function(name){
          return name.uuid.toLowerCase();
        });
        return (_.findIndex(names, { uuid : uuid.toLowerCase() }) === -1) ?  true : false;
    });
  }
}
```

Here, I am using ListService to pre-populate my list in the constructor itself (so it calls the service only once). Then, in my onChange method, I am checking
if a name is unique or not. The isNameUnique is returning a boolean promise. 
Now, I'm trying to get 100% coverage for my test. I'm getting confused about testing isNameUnique method here. My first test is:

(Assuming myList is a json similar to response I will get from service)

```
    this.$scope.myFunction = jasmine.createSpy('myFunction');
    it('should ...', function() {
      this.view.find(NAME_INPUT).val('blue').change(); // my view element.
      this.getList.resolve(myList);
      this.controller.isNameUnique('blue').then(function (unique) {
        expect(unique).toEqual(false); //since blue is already in my json
        expect(this.controller.errorNameInput).toEqual(true); //since its not unique, errornameinput will be set to true
        expect(this.$scope.myFunction).toHaveBeenCalled();
      });
    });
```

I would expect this test to cover the line: `scope.errorNameInput = !reg.test(scope.name) || !scope.isUnique` and invocation of `myFunction()` but it still shows uncovered. Not sure why.

Please let me know if you see anything else wrong since I'm quite new to Angular and Jasmine. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call `$scope.$digest()` to cause your promise to resolve in your test. There is a handy tutorial that discusses this in depth [here](https://netdevplus.wordpress.com/2015/10/20/angularjs-with-typescript-unit-testing-services/)

Hope that helps!

Comment: I was thinking the promise is already resolving that's why its giving me correct result for uniqueness and the test is passing. Let me read up on this. Thanks.

Comment: It's easy to test that theory of your promise resolving - just chuck a `console.log()` in your `then()` and see if it gets hit in your test :)

Comment: Here's a more in-depth article for Angular 1.x (the same principle still applies): http://www.bradoncode.com/blog/2015/07/13/unit-test-promises-angualrjs-q/

Comment: This is helpful to know but still doesn't answer any of my questions.

Comment: added a console.log('promise') in my isUniqueName function's then(). After that, changed my tests to this: it('should return true if name is unique', function() { this.controller.isUniqueName('abcd').then(function (unique) { expect(console.log).toHaveBeenCalledWith('i am in promise'); expect(unique).toEqual(true); }); this.$scope.$digest(); }); The test passed but my coverage report still shows that _.mapValues is not covered.

Comment: I meant: expect(console.log).toHaveBeenCalledWith('promise'); this passed, so I'd assume that the promise was resolved.

Comment: Just before `expect(unique).toEqual(false);` put a console.log - if that prints to your screen when your tests are run, that will quickly verify that your promise has been resolved in your test.

Comment: It works now. That solves part of my problem. I'm still unable to understand why the coverage for scope.errorNameInput = !reg.test(scope.name) || !scope.isUnique; still shows uncovered.

Comment: It's a bit out of scope for this question - feel free to mark this answer as accepted then you can either contact me (GitHub and contact details are on my profile page) or create another question and I can help you further there :)